# Configuring a report to show relative content performance by publish date

Tags: google-analytics

I want to conduct an analysis of our articles, relative to one another, based on the publish date, to answer the question, "How does this article compare with that one, 30, 60, and 90-days from the publish date?"

I have configured a custom dimension to capture the articles' publish dates, but I have no idea how to set them side by side to track "Day 0," "Day 1," "Day 2", etc.

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Good question, but since it's not a coding problem it's probably off-topic on stackoverflow. It might be a better fit for webapps.stackexchange.com or webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I thought it probably involved the GA API in some way, so I just wondered if anyone had coded such a report.